# Could not transfer artifact com.aventstack:extentreports:pom:4.0.9 from/to central : Transfer failed for https:/

Tags: maven, dependencies, extentreports

when I add avantstack:etentreports:4.0.9 dependency on my testNG maven project to generate TestNG reports  I got this error message => Could not transfer artifact com.aventstack:extentreports:pom:4.0.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aventstack/extentreports/4.0.9/extentreports-4.0.9.pom

Also I get this message

Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.aventstack:extentreports:jar:4.0.9

I tried reinstall IntelliJ Idea,
I did mvn clean verify
I did mvn -U clean install

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try with mvn -e and see if there is a stack trace with some more details

Comment: after mvn -e I get this Error detail org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, ...